# Electron React App, path not mapping on JS files in build folder

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have used electron builder to create a windows installer. When I install the app, it does not work as one of the JS files is not being found. The file exists in the build/ folder, and the build folder is included in the electron build. It does not find it as it is looking for the file on the C:\ drive, instead of in the installed directory. See screenshot. It looks like the path is not being set for JS files that exist in the root of the build folder.

I have these settings in my package.json file:

```
"homepage": "./",
"build": {
    "appId": "nonExistentID",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "./src/Main.js"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "extends": null
  },
```

[Screenshot from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY34l.png)